# How can I have a code block with a vertical scrolling feature in the Markdown on GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm dealing with one issue on GitHub and for that, the moderator is requesting me to share the output of certain bash commands in the comments. I'm sharing the output of requested commands in the form of code blocks and I know how to insert code block in Markdown:

```sh
The output of the command
.
.
.
```

However, the problem with the above syntax is that if the command output has let say 500 lines then it will display all the 500 lines in the Markdown output. In fact, there total of 3 such long code blocks in my comment. Because of that, code blocks consume a significant amount of space in my comment and my comment seems too long.

So, is there any way that my code block would display only a limited number of lines with a scrolling feature specific to that block only e.g. it should display only 10 lines, and for the rest of the lines, it should have vertical scrolling. Through this, my comment won't seem too long and the moderator would also be to focus on other non-command text (i.e. content other than code blocks) in my comment.

Comment: I don't think you can. Maybe post core snippets in the comment and links to Gists for the full output? That's how e.g. Terraform issues are encouraged: *"Please create a GitHub Gist containing the debug output. Please do _not_ paste the debug output in the issue, since debug output is long."*

Comment: Oh, had not thought about Gists before for this. Thanks for the suggestions. In my opinion, Gists are not that much convenient for commenting but still, I think better than simple comment which consumes hundreds of line and you get tired of scrolling & scrolling.

Answer (score 18):

GitHub Flavored Markdown allows you to use html tags. So you can use details html block to hide your long code.

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    summary
  </summary>
  details
</details>
```

It looks like this collapsed:

[image: Collapsed]

and expanded:

[image: Expanded]

Comment: This worked for sublime text’s markdown parser, but I’d wonder if you would be able to put a markdown `code block` inside a `<details/>` html tag in other editors.

Comment: It is very common for editors to convert markdown to html so it should be possible in most of them.

Comment: Excellent, but note that ```programming code``` gets formatted as ordinary text if pasted as `details` above. Any solutions for that last-mile problem?

Comment: @mirekphd Yes you can still have it format as code, just wrap it with " ``` ``` "
ex: 
`<details>
<summary>Expand Code</summary>

```tsx
console.log('hello')
```

</details>`

Comment: it sure works! you need a blank line after `</summary>` before you start with the ```. Like described here: https://gist.github.com/pierrejoubert73/902cc94d79424356a8d20be2b382e1ab